# rich:fileUpload more file information

Tags: jsf, upload, richfaces

I want to upload many files and I have chosen rich:fileUpload control for this.

My problem is that I need to add more information for each file, for example the title I want to appear in the application for that file. How can I do that, and send to the fileUploadListener method in order to use the id?

Comment: what RF version you're working with?

Answer (score 2):

Based in your question, the [RichFaces FileUpload demo](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/fileUpload.jsf) has all the info you need to handle file upload for 1 or more files at the same time.

If you want to add more data (like `h:inputText` values and others), then you should pass them using `valueChangeListener` instead `value` tag attribute, because the `fileUploadListener` is an event that happens within an ajax call, so your `UIComponent`s won't call the setters for the attributes.

Some code to explain the behavior:

```
<h:panelGrid cols="2">
    <h:outputText value="File Title:">
    <h:inputText value="#{fileBean.fileTitle}" immediate="false"
        valueChangeListener="#{fileBean.valueChangeFileTitle}" />
    <h:outputText value="File:">
    <rich:fileUpload
        fileUploadListener="#{bean.fileUpload}">
    </rich:fileUpload>
</h:panelGrid>
```

The Bean to handle the requests

```
public class Bean {

    private String fileTitle;

    public Bean() {
    }

    //getters and setters...
    public String getFileTitle() {
        return this.fileTitle;
    }

    public void setFileTitle(String fileTitle) {
        System.out.println("Calling the setter");
        this.fileTitle = fileTitle;
    }

    public void valueChangeFileTitle(ValueChangeEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Calling the ValueChangeListener");
        fileTitle = (String)e.getNewValue();
}

    //this will be invoked by an ajax call
    //the setter of the view won't be invoked for fileTitle
    //instead, we should take its value using valueChangeListener
    public void fileUpload(UploadEvent ue) {
        MyFileManager mfm = MyFileManager.getFileManager();
        MyFile myFile = new MyFile();
        myFile.setTitle(this.fileTitle);
        myFile.setName(ue.getUploadItem().getFileName());
        myFile.setData(ue.getUploadItem().getData());
        mfm.createFile(myFile);
    }
}
```

Also, avoid to use `System.out.println` calls in your code, I'm doing it so you can understand what method will be called, instead use a Logger like [Log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/).

Comment: Hello! Thanks for reply. I am not sure that I was very precisely with what I meant.  I want for each file to have an input text for the title of the file, to send this info to the handler when I press the upload button.

Comment: You can't. You must provide the title for every file, you have 2 ways to do it: 1) add a file input text dinamycally for every file your user adds, 2) ask the title for one file at a time. My example goes for the 2nd way.